# Update table using join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
update salaries set diff = a.diff
from attendence a
join salaries s on s.employees_id = a.employees_id
and s.date = a.date where salaries.employees_id = 22 and date = CURDATE()
```

I have a problem using this code in MySQL

> from is not a valid input at this position"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the syntax of Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL uses a different syntax. Both are non-standard, because multi-table UPDATE is not part of the standard SQL specification.

In MySQL you should use syntax like this:

```
update attendence a join salaries s 
  on s.employees_id = a.employees_id and s.date = a.date
set s.diff = a.diff 
where s.employees_id = 22 and s.date = CURDATE();
```

You should have answered this on your own by reading the [MySQL reference documentation for UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE attendance a
       JOIN salaries s
       ON s.employees_id = a.employees_id AND s.date = a.date
       SET s.diff = a.diff
       WHERE salaries.employees_id = 22 AND date = CURDATE()
```

Hope this works. Ask if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update salaries
Set diff = (
    Select a.diff
    From attendence a
    Join salaries s On s.employees_id = a.employees_id and s.date = a.date
    Where salaries.employees_id = 22 And date = Curdate()
)
```

Also make sure that select query has no error and returns only one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
    update sa  
    set diff = a.diff
    from salaries sa 
    join  attendence a
     on sa.employees_id = a.employees_id
    and sa.date = a.date
     where sa.employees_id = 22 and sa.date = CURDATE()

simple e.g below

UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...
```